# Could you help filtering a collection and creating another in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have created the following to explain my problem.

Given a list with PayDates and periods. I Need to create a new list containing 1 item for each period that is nearest to its Pay Date.

So given the example  the list should return 2 items "1st of the month" and "17th of the month" as they are the closest to their paydate in their period

any suggestions?

```
 private static List<Schedule> GetFilteredScheduleList()
  {
     List<Schedule>oldScheduleList=new List<Schedule>();
     oldScheduleList.Add(new Schedule { PayDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), Id = 1, Name = "1st of the month", Period = SchedulePeriod.Monthly });
     oldScheduleList.Add(new Schedule { PayDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 4), Id = 1, Name = "4th of the month", Period = SchedulePeriod.Monthly });
     oldScheduleList.Add(new Schedule { PayDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 19), Id = 1, Name = "19th of the month", Period = SchedulePeriod.Monthly });
     oldScheduleList.Add(new Schedule { PayDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 3), Id = 1, Name = "3rd of each quarter", Period = SchedulePeriod.Quarterly });
     oldScheduleList.Add(new Schedule { PayDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 8), Id = 1, Name = "8th each quarter", Period = SchedulePeriod.Quarterly });
     oldScheduleList.Add(new Schedule { PayDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 17), Id = 1, Name = "17th of the month", Period = SchedulePeriod.Quarterly });

    // Need to create a new list containing 1 item for each period that is nearest to its Pay Date.Starting point it's today's date.
    //  so the list should return 2 items "1st of the month" and "17th of the month" as they are the closest to their paydate in their period

     List<Schedule> newScheduleList = oldScheduleList.Where(x=>x.PayDate)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should select the `Schedule` item from each period that is closest to now. Is this what you meant?

```
oldScheduleList
    .GroupBy(s => s.Period)
    .Select(
        g => g
              .OrderBy(s => Math.Abs((s.PayDate - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds))
              .First()
    )
```

Edit:

In response to your comment, to get the first item for the period is a little simpler. I've commented a `Where` clause. This will get the first in period from now (i.e. dates that have expired are ignored)

```
oldScheduleList
    .GroupBy(s => s.Period)
    .Select(
        g => g
              //.Where(s => s.Paydate >= DateTime.Now) //filter expired dates
              .OrderBy(s => s.PayDate)
              .First()
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.That works.What about just comparing the dates within the period and get the first.That is what really I am after.Sorry for not explaining properly and thanks for your help

Comment: fantastic all works.THANK YOU!!! if you have time could explain what math.abs does in your first answer.Again thanks

Comment: Math.Abs gives the absolute value of its single parameter. Its logic is as follows: For a value x, if x<0 return -x else return x. Therefore it has the effect of stripping the negative sign from negative numbers. We can use it to get the magnitude of the difference between two values. For instance 2 and 4 have a difference of 2. We can calculate this as follows: Math.Abs(2-4) or Math.Abs(4-2), in both cases the answer is 2.